# How can I take only max values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql request like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.id
INNER JOIN table4 ON table1.id = table4.id
```

I have a problem, I would like receive only max values from table3, for example I receive:

```
ID    Value    
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
3     1
3     2
```

I would like to obtain only the responses with values max:

```
ID    Value
1     3
2     1
3     2
```

There are lot of more columns, that I have hidden.
Have you an idea how to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Is the example provided is data of only Table3? and the output is final output required? or output of table3?

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.id, MAX(t3.value)
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1 = t2.id JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t1.id = t3.id
     table4 t4
     ON t1.id = t4.id
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

use subqueries for table3

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
INNER JOIN ( select id,max(value) as val from table3 group by id) t3 ON table1.id = t3.id
INNER JOIN table4 ON table1.id = table4.id
```

Comment: It seems to be a good solution, but what if I need other values from t3 which are not in the group by clause?

Comment: @anubis according to your need f you can t make it in group by then you could use row_number() analytic function for taking the max value of each ID in subquery and join with others tables